# How to revalidate a nextjs page at midnight?

Tags: next.js

I have a page that needs to "refresh" at midnight.  Currently I have revalidation set at: 60 minutes. But this makes an unnecessary refresh 11 times a day, and sometimes will be an hour late (doesn't refresh correctly/on time aka exactly at midnight).

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const res = await fetch('https://.../posts')
  const posts = await res.json()

  return {
    props: {
      posts,
    },
    revalidate: 3600, // In seconds
  }
}
```

So im thinking about using on demand static regeneration. But this seems like it is only used for when you update a page, hit a button, or add a hook to something.

What other way can i make the page refresh at midnight? Or is on demand static regeneration the ideal way to go?

Comment: You could set a cron job that makes a request to your page at midnight and set the revalidate time to 24 hours. Why only midnight though?

Comment: @vighnesh153 for a shop reveal. page should reveal at midnight. Not before, or 20 minutes after. but right now, its going at 1 hour interval, which means it could be 12:20am when it refreshes...but not midnight. Any other options?

Answer (score 1):

The best option is on demand revalidation and if it's vital enough, you can make another webpage that detects the time in your timezone and sends a request to your revalidation api at your desired time.

Or, you can set revalidate option to 1 hour or 24 hours and deploy 3 minutes or so before that time, which will set the correct revalidation interval.

Answer (score 0):

This might work make sure it only runs once, everytime your server starts

```
const date = new Date();
const hour = 24 - date.getHours();
const min =  date.getMinutes();
const sec = date.getSeconds();
const mili = date.getMilliseconds();
const timeRemaining = ((hour * 60 - min) * 60 - sec) * 1000 - mili;
setTimeout(() =>{
    revalidateTag('data')
    setInterval(()=>{
        revalidateTag('data')
    },24*3600000)
},timeRemaining);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).